# How large can cin input be?

Tags: c++, io, cin

Consider this code:

```
int a;
cin >> a;
```

The input doesn't stop when you enter for example `1` or `2`; it waits until you press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. How does this work? Why does `cin` wait for your input until you press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>?

Comment: If I/O stopped as soon as you typed "1" then how could you enter an integer such as 10000?

Comment: I gave it as an example. The input can be "1","2", "1000", or any integer you want.

Comment: @J.M You missed Brandin's point. If the input were "1000", but the input operation ended after each character, then your program would not be able to read all four characters into the single `int`. Fortunately, terminals generally buffer line-by-line by default which avoids this problem.

Comment: I'll be more concrete. The question is, why the input doesn't stop after the first single space encountered?

Comment: it should also stop if you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> (and no newline in the input stream)

Comment: @J.M: It would, if your terminal passed on your keystrokes to your program at that time.

Comment: @J.M The answer is already given as answers below, but another way to think of it is that your C++ program "blocks" (pauses) on the cin ">>" operation until an entire line is read from the terminal. That is due to line-by-line buffering of the terminal that was already mentioned.

Comment: The issue here really has nothing to do with C++. Your question is about how your terminal works and how information is passed between processes on your operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cin` just has a buffer behind it that gets filled up with input and then gets emptied as you use the extraction operator (`>>`). When and how it gets filled up depends on the platform. In Unix-like systems, for example, the input terminal is in either canonical or non-canonical mode. In canonical mode, input is made available line by line. In non-canonical mode, it is available immediately. It's possible to change between these modes (check `man termios`).

The actual size of the standard input buffer is implementation-defined.

Comment: Line-by-line means your program receives input one line at a time. Obviously then it is down to whatever `cin >>` operations you have programmed as to what happens with that input.

Comment: @J.M No, it means your terminal will not send anything to your program until it has been given an entire line. Then your program will receive it as input. If you want to read it line-by-line in your program, you'd have to use `getline`, but there's no reason you can't read word-by-word or letter-by-letter (or whatever).

Comment: This means that, if i want to read a string from the terminal, the largest string i can read is as large as one line?

Comment: @J.M Well how long is the largest line? As long as the user wants it to be! I don't mean a line as in however it's wrapped inside your terminal - I mean a line that ends in `\n`.

Answer (score 4):

Your runtime environment and your terminal control the raw keyboard input. Typically, they only send the input to the application line by line, to allow for editing. You have to speak to your terminal, in a platform-dependent way, if you want it to send you the keyboard input immediately.

(This is often referred to as "raw" mode, as opposed to the usual, line-buffered "cooked" mode. Note that the cooked mode also handles backspace and delete and cursor movement and all that.)